# Could not parse JSON DATA from finance google

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can someone please help me in parsing the below jsonData into a nsDictionary object

> [ { "id": "22144" ,"t" : "AAPL" ,"e" : "NASDAQ" ,"l" : "111.57"
>   ,"l_fix" : "111.57" ,"l_cur" : "111.57" ,"s": "2" ,"ltt":"4:00PM EST"
>   ,"lt" : "Nov 28, 4:00PM EST" ,"lt_dts" : "2016-11-28T16:00:01Z" ,"c" :
>   "-0.22" ,"c_fix" : "-0.22" ,"cp" : "-0.20" ,"cp_fix" : "-0.20" ,"ccol"
>   : "chr" ,"pcls_fix" : "111.79" ,"el": "111.56" ,"el_fix": "111.56"
>   ,"el_cur": "111.56" ,"elt" : "Nov 28, 8:00PM EST" ,"ec" : "-0.01"
>   ,"ec_fix" : "-0.01" ,"ecp" : "-0.01" ,"ecp_fix" : "-0.01" ,"eccol" :
>   "chr" ,"div" : "0.57" ,"yld" : "2.04" } ]

```
#define QUERY_PREFIX @"https://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:AAPL"
#define QUERY_SUFFIX @"NSE:AAPL"

@implementation YQL

- (NSDictionary *) query: (NSString *)statement {


    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", QUERY_PREFIX, [statement stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], QUERY_SUFFIX];
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSUInteger firstCurlyBracePos = [dataString rangeOfString:@"[" options:0].location;
    NSUInteger lastCurlyBracePos = [dataString rangeOfString:@"]" options: NSBackwardsSearch].location;
    NSString *jsonString = nil;
    if(firstCurlyBracePos != NSNotFound && lastCurlyBracePos != NSNotFound) {
        jsonString = [dataString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(firstCurlyBracePos, (lastCurlyBracePos-firstCurlyBracePos)+1)];
    }

    NSData *someData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@ Nirmal",jsonString);
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:someData options:0 error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@ Anand",results);
    NSString* latestLoans = [results objectForKey:@"el_cur"];

    NSLog(@"loans: %@", latestLoans);


    if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] JSON error: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error.localizedDescription);

    return results;
}

@end
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI
>   objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61800000d010'

Comment: It is a valid json. And you are using `NSJSONSerialization`. But since first object is array so use Patrick's suggestion.

Comment: Why are you converting your `JSON` `NSData` to a string, and then converting the string back to `NSData`? Looks to me like you're trying to use string parsing to get rid of the outer array. Don't do that. Just convert the whole thing to a JSON object and parse that. And are the comment double slashes ("//") part of the data you're getting, or did you add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you're trying to parse is an array, not an object, as denoted by the enclosing square brackets. So NSJSONSerialization is going to return an NSArray here, not an NSDictionary. Since it seems like there is only one object in this array, you can access it like so:

```
NSArray *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:someData options:0 error:&error];

NSDictionary *object = results.firstObject;

NSString *latestLoans = object["el_cur"];
```